# Return value from array inside a function based on parameter

Tags: arrays, bash, function, parameters

gurus. I'm developing a bash script and learning about arrays in bash. I read a couple of howto about that but my head blew up. I used to program in php and bash is new and "rudimentary" for me.

I'm going to put multilang support to my script and I need to define all visible phrases in different arrays to get them calling a function with a parameter. Hard to explain I'll put what I want to do in php what is my "comfort" language and then my not working aproximation in bash script.

```
Php:
function english($index) {
    $strings=array(
                "phrase1",
                "phrase2"
                );
    return $strings[$index];
}
echo english(1); //It produces (zero based) "phrase2"
```

Ok, now my poor bash script trying to do the  same:

```
Bash:
function english() {
    strings=("phrase1" "phrase2")
    return ${strings[$1]}
}
echo english 2
```

How can I return the desired value of array calling a function containing the array and based on the function parameter?

Anyone has a good bash manual to do some practices about this? Thank you.

Comment: bash functions returns int as status values, not Strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return values in shell are for exit codes, not data. Instead, write the value to standard output (and capture it with command substitution, if necessary).

```
english () {
    strings=("phrase1" "phrase2")
    echo "${strings[$1]}"
}

english 1          # Arrays are indexed from 0
word=$(english 0)  # word=phrase1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function english {
    strings=("phrase1" "phrase2") 
    echo ${strings[$1]}
}
#Arrays are zero-based
english 1;
```

[Bash Guide for Beginners](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/)